# Maven archetype to modify an existing project?

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I'm trying to create an archetype that would add some data in an existing POM file.

Actually, this archetype would specify the distributionManagement for a project which is not configured for that.

I know that the allowPartial attribute in the archetype.xml file allow something like that, but I didn't figure out how to do it.

Is there a way to do so ? Do I have to use an existing plugin ? Do I have to create my own ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4):

You simply run the `archetype:generate` command in the directory of the project you want to update (with all the parameters - equal to the groupId/artifactId/version of the existing project).

Note, that apart from `<allowPartial>true</allowPartial>` you need `<archetype-descriptor partial="true">` in your archetype-metadata.xml

Answer (score 0):

When creating the archetype, set the value of the allowPartial element to 'true' in archetype.xml - example http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-create-an-archetype-that-can-run-on-an-existing-project.html

More info on creating Maven archetypes: http://code.google.com/p/jianwikis/wiki/HowToCreateMavenArchetypeFromProject

It's a belated answer, I know. I just happened to find the question tonight, and I happened to have discovered the answer to it, tonight, in looking into the matter, myself - better late than never, then? ;}

Granted, I'm still trying to figure out how to *apply* a Maven 'allowPartual' 'true' archetype to an existing project - might have to ask a question about that, myself, here

Comment: When I tried this I got following error 

Don't override file ~\dev\pushkartest2\src\main\java\com\pushkartest2\action\Action.java


`Action.java' is the that get created by artifact